# unshift adding too many variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of player names in an array `playerNameArray`. I also have a second multidimensional array `playerHistoryArray` which has players game history.

What I wish to do is go through each player in my `playerNameArray` and check if they exist in the `playerHistoryArray` entry. If it does exist I want to add the `playerHistoryArray` entry to a new array but using the `playerName` as a unique id field in this new array `playersPlayArray`. I am doing this using the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < (playerNameArray.length); i++) {

  playersName = playerNameArray[i];

  for (var j = 0; j < (playerHistoryArray.length); j++) {

    for (var details in playerHistoryArray[j]) {
      if (String((playerHistoryArray[j][details])).substr(0, 4) === "Player Name:") {
        currentPlayerName = String(handTotalArray[j][details]).substr(18);
        currentPlayerName = currentPlayerName.substring(0, currentPlayerName.indexOf(" ") + 1);
        if (String(currentPlayerName).trim() === String(playersName).trim()) {
          doesPlayerExist = true;
        }
      }
    }

    if (doesPlayerExist === true) {
      playersPlayArray[playersPlayCounter] = handTotalArray[j];
      playersPlayArray[playersPlayCounter].unshift(String(playersName).trim());
      playersPlayCounter = playersPlayCounter + 1;
      doesPlayerExist = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This is working perfectly except for one thing. When I use `unshift` to grab the players name to use as the unique id in the new array when I iterate through my playernames array if a second player appears in the `playerHistoryArray` of another player then he is being added to the `playersPlayArray` as well. So I'd see the array as such:

Player1
Player2
rest of info

But I don't want this I just want Player1 in that array entry and Player2 in his own array entry. I have gone through the code a thousand times and can't understand why it's doing this. Especially as the `playersPlayCounter` is incrementing all the time so how is the later player name being added to earlier entries in the new array `playersPlayArray`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: All those explicit calls to `String()` are probably unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit them out